# Mysterious filesystem issues setting up web server

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, web-server, windows

After installing Raspbian on an a 16 GB SSD card and booting up it with the Raspberry Pi

I tried to run this guide: http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server
while installing Hexxeh's RPI update tool, it says that the storage is full.
Running "df -h" shows that its size is 4GB and that it is full.

When plugin the SSD with an Adapter in my Windows 8 Laptop it displays 40.1 MB free of 59.9 MB

What might the issue be?

Comment: did you run sudo raspi-config and expand the root file system?

Comment: How to *not* make?

Comment: Windows cannot see the second partition.  This is normal and it was that way before you changed anything.

Comment: @SteveRobillard raspi-config fixed it!

Comment: As @goldilocks says Windows cannot understand many of the filesystem types that GNU/Linux handles without blinking - it may just moan about an unformatted partition and invite you to format it ready to use (at least it does for Hard Disks, it may be a bit more reticent about other storage media types) - don't let it!  There are free / commercial drivers for M$ Windoze that can do this - which can be a relief if you ever have to "fix" things with a badly not working RPi and haven't embraced GNU/Linux for your Desktop PC 8-). I sometimes use the GPL 2 [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you need to do when starting from a new install is expanding the disk to utilize all available storage. For reasons of compactness and compatibility, the default images provided for the RPi are small and have little extra space (typically <4GB).

Using `raspi-config`, or the Menu option for Raspberry Pi Configuration in the latest Raspbian, you can "Expand Filesystem" and make the RPi use all of the available space. Do a reboot and then start installing programs and following guides.

Make sure to run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure you have the latest & greatest versions of all components)